# .htpasswd in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello there I want to password protect one of my controllers in codeigniter. This is the code in .htaccess

```
# password-protect single file
<Files my_controller.php>
AuthName "my_controller.php"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home2/afolder/.htpasswds/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
```

the problem is that myController.php will show up in my url as `/my_controller/` (no .php) so the protection has no effect...can I do something to overcome this problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally the solution was as simple as that...

```
# password-protect single file
<Files my_controller>
AuthName "my_controller"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home2/afolder/.htpasswds/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
```

just removed .php and everything is fine...

Comment: Just to add, you need to make sure you do this in your .htaccess file before any URL rewriting, rather than adding it on the end like I did on auto-pilot!