# How to apply htpasswd to codeigniter admin?

Tags: codeigniter, admin

I need to apply .htpasswd to my CI admin panel. But i have no separate folder for admin, How can i apply without having a folder. I have only admin folder in views, controllers and models are not separately written.
Please help me how can i make my admin panel secure with basic authentication.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the solution found in this post

[.htpasswd in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816031/htpasswd-in-codeigniter)

or this

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/141775/

Comment: Thanks, i have tried the above solutions but they didn't work for me as i have no folder 'admin' to secure.

Comment: @Reetika you don't need any folder for the first solution for sure, just a path to your controller without `.php`

Comment: yes i know, you are write. but if i apply password to only one controller i can simply edit url to access other admin controller

Comment: What do you suggest to do then? How do you see your authentication should work then?